# JavaScript unexpected error message (Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, text-editor

I have a code which is works fine in jsfiddle but when I put the code inside my `index.php` file, and I click onto the buttons, I get the following message for each clicks : `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'`. The error code is in the 2nd line, but the second line is ony contains comment. Any idea what causes this issue?

```css
#container #editor1 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 602px;
  margin: 0px auto 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container fieldset {
  margin: 2px auto 0px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: none;
}

#container button {
  width: 5ex;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border: none;
}

#container img {
  width: 100%;
}

#container .bold {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}

#container .italic::before {
  content: "I";
}

#container .align-left {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEsAAAA1CAAAAAAsDUmHAAAAIGNIUk0AAHomAACAhAAA+gAAAIDoAAB1MAAA6mAAADqYAAAXcJy6UTwAAAACYktHRAAAqo0jMgAAAAlwSFlzAAAuIwAALiMBeKU/dgAAAAd0SU1FB+MIHAYHAD13ih8AAAIrSURBVEjHzZaxTxRBFMa/N7OH0FJqSwnChsTYnomKnJUKFOo1JrbGwpBYmwCV0X9AvMRK1IJ4OTtjYyCQ44xWtNpaa9x5z+IIt7vHbGYeV3DlJvfLm2++b76XCEb2S3DGWeJIRxBLJZboJxShAkvo94uuajBJH00ewZIj1J8bu4Y1LLPd/jLRh/VZLtnaPacTjGp7b5suyev1C5zp5CL8LGhPuASnFJ9xGXm9rNRXN0QVAZInV8Tm75FkfeWHSi+eTkueAHGaKv3Fpux7w6xDGTOcx8G3EeQx5m+WKlgiUZZgkJ9Ff9/sB9+jzN8dF/KwhOR2OzyPhrc+mmFYn8X2fXuMw8VPOu+W2HrmwmFUHhMcQjxnJMyAasEZIuAifHpZaTRbMXrduwnru0fCq5WDYL14bqHKq4LFxRh/SZW/yEU8OWQrMwR72jjmWE65DQxmHORRPRdT+S2UT10dKr1a6m2hB5vKfuTm60LXOtveTEj1GJJpLTeczefxG/BPe3u9hhTyOAWj7EeDqUI/Gtxa6Cj1yq7dgcnPJeZDq6vSi9P7pqA9SMYeqv011LXItKyhvRB0+s11QIjp7ZN7+ZjFUb19Ys8cZ9v0voejpmcr3kKhp2sU3h2yuu7tWmc/r8WckTeu1523H3dgI/JY46918ep1HiYJP6PBBa/2Fksv9yL6MZtf9vYjyXjneS+8H2cfT3i1B8nksxiLS2U/ShaxRkvlXjjaPOJMsf4DQ22vjD/V/uUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
  width: 40px;
}

#container .align-center {
  width: 38px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAOCAYAAAAvxDzwAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAADRJREFUOBFjYGBg2ArE/6mEtzIBDaImADlsCAJSwhSkFgVQGoYjIMwIpdfRdAhJUYMrHQIAWPdBdW2q70gAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <fieldset>
    <button class="fontStyle italic" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);" title="Italicize Highlighted Text"></button>
    <button class="fontStyle bold" onclick="document.execCommand( 'bold');" title="Bold Highlighted Text"></button>
    <button class="fontStyle strikethrough" onclick="document.execCommand( 'strikethrough',false,null);"><strikethrough></strikethrough></button>
    <button class="fontStyle align-left" onclick="document.execCommand( 'justifyLeft',false,null);"><justifyLeft></justifyLeft></button>
    <button class="fontStyle align-center" onclick="document.execCommand( 'justifyCenter',false,null);"><justifyCenter></justifyCenter></button>
  </fieldset>
  <div id="editor1" contenteditable="true" data-text="Enter comment...."></div>
</div>
```

[image: picture of the error message]

Comment: I would hesitate to use a deprecated feature if it were me https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: Please note `execCommand()` is alredy deprecated, see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). You can mention browsers you tried it in. Have you tried encapsulate called function to easily debug your code?

Comment: FWIW the default for `<button></button>` is `type="submit"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: @FilipKováč I am currently using firefox, but I haven't tried it in different browsers yet. And I have not tried encapsulate. Honestly I don't really know what is that.

Comment: @scrummy encapsulate => `onclick=funcName(yourParams)` and inside of funcName you can have your code, in this case `execCommand()`.

Comment: @FilipKováč Okay I tried it and its working. I don't know why I haven't tried it sooner. If you write it out as answer I am going to accept it!

Comment: Yes, the encapsulation working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate your function inside of `onclick` event.
Change it from

```
onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);"
```

to

```
var onClickFunc = (params) {
     // do your stuff here
}

onclick="onClickFunc(params)"
```